# Display attribute context with escaping xml characters using jstl

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, escaping, jstl, el

I have a page with jstl included.
In jsp file I have to pull out context atribute:

```
<%= pageContext.getServletContext().getAttribute("NameOfMyAtribute")%>
```

and display it escaping xml characters:

```
<c:out escapeXml="true" value="  ?  "/>
```

How to do it? What is the order of processing? If I simply put:

```
<c:out escapeXml="true" value="<%= pageContext.getServletContext().getAttribute("NameOfMyAtribute")%>"/>
```

It wont work, and even if it probably display (without xml characters) text <*%= pageContext.getServletContext().getAttribute("NameOfMyAtribute")%>* instead of invoking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<c:out value="${NameOfMyAttribute}"/>
```

or

```
<c:out value="${applicationScope.NameOfMyAttribute}"/>
```

Forget about scriptlets. They shouldn't be used anymore. The EL looks for page-scope attributes, then request-scope attributes, then session-scope attributes, the application-scope attributes.

And `escapeXml` is true by default (since it's the only thing `<c:out>` does)